# Angular Array Observable needs to be called twice to work properly

Tags: asp.net, angular

I'm new to Angular and I have a button function that subscribes to an observable and puts the returned data into an array. When I first do the call, the array is empty, but if I click the button again, the array populates correctly. I'm not sure why.

I tried unsubscribing from the observable but that didn't work for me.

This is the code I'm working with:

```
userList: UserRm[] = []

assignUser() {  

  if (this.form.invalid)
    return;

  this.userProjectService.findUserProject({ projectId: this.projectId ?? '' })
    .subscribe(response => { this.userList = response; console.log(this.userList) }, this.handleError);



  if (this.userList.length == 0) {
    this.openDialog("already-assigned", <any>this.form.value.email);
    //this.alreadyAssignedError = true;
    console.log("userlist = 0, User is already assigned to project.");
  }
 else {
    //else logic. 
   //this only gets triggered after pushing the button twice
}
```

At 'if (this.userList.length == 0) ', even if there should be data in userList, it is empty. If I push the button again, then the userList is populated correctly.

**UPDATE:**

I changed things around a bit and now I get slightly different results, but not quite the behavior I'm looking for. Now on the first click, the userList is populated correctly and I get the right results.
However, if I presses the button again, userList doesn't update with the new API call, it stays the same. Before, I got an error message before a success, now I get two successes. On the third time pressing the button, the userList updates properly and I get an error message (the expected result).

I moved my subscription call into a different function

```
getId(value: any) {
    this.projectId = value;
    console.log(this.projectId);

    this.userProjectService.findUserProject({ projectId: this.projectId ?? '' })
      .subscribe(response => { this.userList = response; console.log(this.userList) }, this.handleError);
  }
```

Then I called that function in my assignUsers function:

```
this.getId(this.projectId);
```

Comment: Your IF/ELSE need to be inaide the subscription block, after you set value to an array.

Answer (score 0):

It works, from Misha Mashina. I had to move the If/Else into the subscription call and it now has the correct behavior.

```
assignUser() {  
    

    if (this.form.invalid)
      return;


    this.userProjectService.findUserProject({ projectId: this.projectId ?? '' })
      .subscribe(response => {
        this.userList = response; console.log(this.userList);

        if (this.userList.length == 0) {
          this.openDialog("already-assigned", <any>this.form.value.email);
          //this.alreadyAssignedError = true;
          console.log("userlist = 0, User is already assigned to project.");
        }
        
}
```